# Odoo To-Do application

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

This is my `todo.task` odoo object

```
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name='todo.task'
    name=fields.Char('Description',required=1,help="what needs to be done")
    is_done=fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active1=fields.Boolean('Active?',default=True)
    user_id=fields.Many2one('res.users','Responsible')
    date_deadline=fields.Date('Deadline')
```

There are two menu items namely **To-Do Tasks** and **To-Do Users** which are of relevance here.  I have created 4 **ToDo** which are responsible by 3 users(nicole,jack,Administrator). The menu item **To-Do Tasks** and its tree view works as intended, which has 4 entries.[image]

When I press the **To-Do Users** I want to print all the **unique** *users* that are *responsible* for *ToDOs*, instead of this [image] where **nicole** is repeated **twice**

currently its its tree view is as follows

```
<record id="view_tree_todo_users" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Employee data</field>
    <field name="model">todo.task</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree >     
            <field name="user_id" />
        </tree>

    </field>
</record>
```

**How can I list all the unique users in the second menu?**

Answer (score 1):

you can't just hide duplicates from tree view because first 'nicole' and second 'nicole' are not same objects. They are two different object so when you asking to print 'user-id' it gives you this result.

One wrong way to hide duplicates in field user-id is unique constraint but if you will do this, then nicole can't create second task :D so it's bad idea.

I think from your model it's wrong to get unique names because it's normal that one person could have several tasks(it gives you correct results).

So if you want to get unique names then you must inherit 'res.users' and add some boolean field to res.users and then in tree view list all the users from 'res.users' where this boolean is true.

```
<field name="display_name" attrs="{'invisible':[('has_task','=',True)]}/>
```

Answer is not tested :)
Hope it helped you.

Comment: It is `res.partner` where user information is stored not `res.user` don't know why. How can I set/reset the 'has_task' field automatically while creating a _todo task_

Comment: Hi again, I meant 'res.partner' it's my mistake :)
Now listen me carefully :) this are steps what you need to go to achieve your goals: 1. inherit res.partner and add new hidden non required boolean field to this model and after this 2. when you are picking 'res.partner' you have "link" to this object (its relation by relational field in your case many 2 one) and when you are saving created object you are running function create() so you must define create method to browse to the many2one object and set 'has_task' field to True

Comment: I think it is easier to create a new model called `todo.user` without inheriting from anything(res.users or res.partner). When I create a new model inherited from `res.users` and try to enter the *Responsible* field the drop down (Create and Edit button) it will show the form view of `res.users` (in edit mode) with a lot of field. Which is really messy as we haven't wrote form view of our new model.

Comment: it's an option too good luck, but creating new module will be problematic because after new module you have two module for users and it's not look good for me. example: you have user user2332665 and now for tasks you must make another todo.user for user2332665 so, user2332665  has two different user account. Think about it

Comment: I have created a new model `todo.users` and used a calculated field to find `todo_count=fields.Integer('todo count', compute='compute_user_todo');
def compute_user_todo(self):
  self.todo_count=len(self.env['todo.task'].search([('user_id', '=', self.id)]))
  return 1`